# How to avoid bouncing up the elements when typing in input at android web

Tags: javascript, android, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a problem that I can not solve, in Android devices when you put text in the input,
so due to the appearance of the keyboard,
all the elements are popped up - I attached pictures.

How can this problem be solved?

[image: Before]
[image: After]

How can I turn off the default css settings of browsers in Android? Because in iOS it works great

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Popping up keyboard is resizing `Activity` by default, thus it has less space so web content also, and it looks like in your case web content still trying to "fill whole space" trying to align to bottom, center etc. - that depends of params set in CSS

Consider preventing this `Activity` resizing by `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` line in manifest

```
<activity 
    android:name="your.package.activity.WebActivity" 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" 
    ... rest of params
```

with this line your `Activity` won't be resized, instead of that keyboard will show up "above" your `View` (so will cover half of content). you can also try with `adjustPan` value, for sure not `adjustResize`. some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#windowSoftInputMode)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but this is an web app not a mobile app, where can i put this line in web app?

Comment: right, my code is desired to work with Android native Java/Kotlin app. for web page opened in browser I would recomend you to change dynamic values (100%, vh etc.) to static values after onload window, these should be preserved after `Activity` resize (web browsers are also native Android apps)

Comment: I did it, unfortunately it still does not solve the problem :(

Comment: I agree with @matan3sh that workaround seems to stop working this year.